# Will I have issues if I enter China on a Q2 (multi-entry family visit visa) but will not visit family?

Tags: visas, china, regulations

I obtained a Q2 visa since a direct family member of mine lives in China. I need to enter China soon for an event, but will be going to a different city from where they live and will not have time to meet them. Would I still be able to enter, just saying that I will visit my family, even if that is not true? I'm iffy on the idea of lying to customs but this is what has been recommended to me.

Comment: Lying to officials is **NEVER** a good idea, and you need to not do that. Getting the appropriate category visa is the right thing

Answer (score 2):

In 99% of the cases the border control probably won't ask you anything in detail for Q2 holders; but if you are asked it is not a good idea to lie. Or just book a ticket to your family's place. It is not prohibited to travel for tourism or business (not employment or study) if you entered legally on a Q2 visa.

The decision is yours to make. Note that China usually does not allow holding two visas of different categories, so your Q2 visa is likely to be cancelled, even if it can be valid for 10 years (for Canadian and US citizens).

Comment: Would I be able to hold two different visas on two different passports (I have dual citizenship)? I want to see if I can get a F visa through the event (it's an educational thing) since it seems the most applicable.

Comment: Trying to evade the rules is asking for trouble. If you are open an honest about it when applying that wouldn't be a problem, but then they wouldn't give it.